# Why is class variable' s type the supclass's type?

Tags: python

Here, the content of parenthesis means superclass.

```py
class Tag(enum.Enum):
    a = 1
    b = 2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Tag.a)
```

output is as follows:

```
Tag.a
```

After I replaced `"Tag.a"` with `"Tag.a.value"`, I got the output as follows:

```
1
```

Why is class variable' s type the superclass's type?

I can't understand the code. Please interpret the result as explicitly as possible.

Comment: It's powered by crazy metaclasses. Normal class variables don't work like that.

Answer (score 3):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) are quite good:

> enum — Support for enumerations New in version 3.4.
>
> Source code: Lib/enum.py
>
> An enumeration is a set of symbolic names (members) bound to unique,
>   constant values. Within an enumeration, the members can be compared by
>   identity, and the enumeration itself can be iterated over.
>
> [...]
>
> Creating an Enum Enumerations are created using the class syntax,
>   which makes them easy to read and write. An alternative creation
>   method is described in Functional API. To define an enumeration,
>   subclass Enum as follows:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> from enum import Enum
> >>> class Color(Enum):
> ...     RED = 1
> ...     GREEN = 2
> ...     BLUE = 3
> ...
> ```
>
> Note Enum member values Member values can be anything: int, str, etc..
>   If the exact value is unimportant you may use auto instances and an
>   appropriate value will be chosen for you. Care must be taken if you
>   mix auto with other values.
>
> Note Nomenclature The class Color is an enumeration (or enum)
>
> The attributes Color.RED, Color.GREEN, etc., are enumeration members
>   (or enum members) and are functionally constants.
>
> The enum members have names and values (the name of Color.RED is RED,
>   the value of Color.BLUE is 3, etc.)
>
> Note Even though we use the class syntax to create Enums, Enums are
>   not normal Python classes. See [How are Enums different?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#how-are-enums-different) for more
>   details.
>   Enumeration members have human readable string representations:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> print(Color.RED)
> Color.RED
> ```